# the maximum possible entries a network can accept in RAFT consensus?

Tags: consensus

Suppose a network of 5 nodes uses RAFT consensus protocol. Each nodes maintains a transactions log which consist of list of log entries. Each log entry again consist of index, term and command. The current log structure which consist of transaction log of all nodes present in the network is as follows -

[image: Transaction log of all nodes]

Then the maximum possible committed entries (i.e. the network can accept entries upto that command) are ?

Answer (score 0):

In RAFT 
First thing is leader must be elected.
To update a data in log, leader must get majority of voting.

In this case after first 2 rounds leader changes.
in 3rd and 4th round new leader updates data.
But in final round leader doesn't get opportunity to update the "e7" as the leader doesn't get majority.